# How to make procedurally generated terrain look realistic

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, 3d-meshes, terrain-rendering

I generated a terrain using a technique from [this blog post](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/), everything worked well and I got the wanted result.
This is what my generated island looks like:

[image]

As you can see the terrain have a polygon structure.
Here is the graph that generated this mesh:

[image]

This is the code used to generate this mesh from the graph:

```
    void DrawPolygons(){
    List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    List<int> triangles=new List<int>();
    List<Color32> colors = new List<Color32>();

    foreach(Center c in centers){
        float zp = zScale*c.elevation;
        vertices.Add(new Vector3(((Vector2)c.point).x,zp,((Vector2)c.point).y));
        Color c0 = getColor(c);
        colors.Add(c0);
        int centerIndex=vertices.Count-1;
        var edges = c.borders;
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int firstIndex = 0;

        for(int i =0;i<c.borders.Count;i++){
            if(edges[i].v0 == null && edges[i].v1 == null)
                break;

            //get voronoi edge
            Corner corner0 = edges[i].v0;
            Corner corner1 = edges[i].v1;

            //get vertices height
            float z0 = zScale*corner0.elevation;
            float z1 = zScale*corner1.elevation;

            //add color
            if(edges[i].river>0){
                c0 = Color.cyan;
            }else{
                c0 = getColor(c);
            }

            colors.Add(c0);
            colors.Add(c0);

            //creat voronoi edge points
            Vector3 v0 = new Vector3(((Vector2)corner0.point).x,z0,((Vector2)corner0.point).y);
            Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(((Vector2)corner1.point).x,z1,((Vector2)corner1.point).y);

            //add points to vertices
            vertices.Add(v0);
            var i2 = vertices.Count - 1;
            vertices.Add(v1);
            var i3 = vertices.Count - 1;

            //add triangles calculating surface normals so i can always add triangles clockwise correctly
            var surfaceNormal = Vector3.Cross (v0-(new Vector3(((Vector2)c.point).x,zp,((Vector2)c.point).y)), v1-(new Vector3(((Vector2)c.point).x,zp,((Vector2)c.point).y)));
            if(surfaceNormal.y>0)
                AddTriangle(triangles, centerIndex, i2, i3);
            else
                AddTriangle(triangles, centerIndex, i3, i2);

            firstIndex = i2;
            lastIndex = i3;
        }
    }

    //calculating uv's
    Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < uvs.Length; i++)
    {
        uvs[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x / SIZE, vertices[i].z / SIZE);
    }

    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
    mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
    mesh.uv = uvs;
    mesh.colors32 = colors.ToArray();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    meshFilter.sharedMesh = mesh;
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;

}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to have a noisy/realistic looking terrain from this. How would I implement such a thing?

Basically I want something with no hard edges, terrain that looks smooth but not too smooth, something like [this video shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8XsRYsc7Nk):

[image]

Comment: Define "noisy/realistic".

Comment: Basically no hard edges, a terrain that looks smooth but not too smooth, something like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FR8XsRYsc7Nk%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DR8XsRYsc7Nk&docid=5CB2y9R7ep09DM&tbnid=WE99dC_tYVVqgM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjB06nPtoXjAhULy4UKHca_CXsQMwhuKBowGg..i&w=1280&h=720&bih=610&biw=1229&q=procedurally%20generated%20terrain&ved=0ahUKEwjB06nPtoXjAhULy4UKHca_CXsQMwhuKBowGg&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: Use gouraud shading, tessellate mesh and run terrain erosion algorithm.

Comment: Thank you ithink this is exactly what i needed i'm gonna research this now and see what i come up with.

Comment: Check Sebastian Lague on youtube, he has multiple videos on procedural terrain generation. Will help you a lot

Comment: @Nick yes i've checked his videos out his procedural terrain generation tutorials helped me and also i've seen that he made a hydraulic erosion tutorial too wich was my next step

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that Unity already has a very nice [terrain system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Terrain.html) out-of-the-box. It gives you a lot of nice features for free like LOD, occlusion culling and a lot more. Also, it can look pretty neat. You can still generate terrain procedurally, but the [input data](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain-terrainData.html) it expects isn't a mesh but a [height map in form of a two-dimensional array of floats](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html). So if you want to keep using that cell-based algorithm, you will have to convert it to output a heightmap instead of a list of vertices.

But no matter which technical implementation you choose to render your map: If you want to generate a landscape which combines discernible large features with small details, then it is usually a good idea to layer multiple terrain generation algorithms on top of each other. Use a pass with a high amplitude and a low resolution to generate the basic shapes (like you already do), and then run another pass with a lower amplitude but a higher resolution to create detail.

You could, for example, apply the same algorithm you are already using again for each cell to subdivide it further. Or you could use a completely different algorithm to "rough up" each cell like [Perlin Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

Also, don't underestimate the effect of good textures. A high-resolution texture with a good normal map could make a terrain surface look a lot less plastic-like. Keep in mind that you need to also call [`mesh.RecalculateTangents()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateTangents.html) on your mesh for normal maps to render correctly.

I am looking forward to exploring the procedurally generated worlds in your game.

Comment: i like the idea of using this to produce a height map to then implement it in the existing unity terrain system but i think that will make me loose the benefits of the graph based terrain generation wich helps me define biomes and maybe even use it for pathfinding later on. For now i will try to add more algorithmes to this like tessalation and different erosion algorithmes and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to generate realistic terrain is to *simulate* physical processes like

- corrosion

  - either with a "uniform" corrosion algorithm or simulation of water or both
- simulation of interaction of multiple sediment layers, don't forget that the origin of a lot of amazing landscapes are the sediments and the interactions of them with water
  underneath, like stone, dirt, sand, etc.
- plate tectonics(?) (no idea which game simulates that but it's maybe possible)